# Jquery script not loaded properly

Tags: jquery

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title> La Stoà - Homepage </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        [...]
    </body>

    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>

</html>
```

I've already tried putting the scripts before the `</body>` tag or inside the `<head></head>` but nothing changes.

This is the situation in the editor:
[image]

Maybe the problem is the library not loaded? No, that's not the problem, I checked this way:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(() => { 

    $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");

});
</script>
```

I put this between the library loading and my script loading, and it works.
Then, I used the same code (without `<script>` tags, obviously) in the main.js file and it didn't work!

What I'm doing wrong? I really cannot understand

EDIT:

```
 JSLint (3)
1   
'$' was used before it was defined. $(document).ready(() => {
1   
Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'. $(document).ready(() => {
1   
Stopping. (20% scanned).    $(document).ready(() => {
 ESLint (1)
1   
ERROR: Parsing error: Unexpected token )    $(document).ready(() => {
```

Comment: The minimal code you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rxo3fpef/. Please show more of your actual code which causes the error

Comment: There is no problem in the code. These are JSLint and ESLint errors, not JavaScript errors.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know it works; in fact the problem occurs when the script is in main.js, not inside the html

Comment: @Xufox I understand it, but the problem remains: when I load the page with the preview, the code doesn't work

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is a useless statement. What happens? What doesn't happen? What are you expecting to happen? The code you've shown works absolutely fine. Unfortunately we're not mind readers to be able to see your code, so unless you give us more information we cannot help you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan anything happens! It seems like the script doesn't even exist because borders (in the test) are not added

Comment: As I showed you in the fiddle above, the code you've given us works fine. We cannot debug a problem you're not showing us.

Comment: Are you sure you have actually referenced the libraries correctly? The code looks like it should work so check that you have referenced the esLint library correctly

Comment: Voting close following "answer" by OP:  This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one **was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers**.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to move your jquery `<script>` tag in the head instead of the body. In addition to that you could also use `$(function(){...})` as onready-listener.

Comment: Having the script just before the `</body>` is actually better in most browsers, and the OP is already using a document.ready handler.

Answer (score -2):

The silliest error: files had to be saved before launching

I'm sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: I agree, this should be deleted as it was a user error that will not help any future visitors.